# Cant inject null value into class

Tags: android, android-fragments, dependency-injection, roboguice

I have a fragment that I want to reuse. Its functionality is the same, only the layout changes

I am using roboguice to inject views by id into the variables

I added this view for example:

```
@Nullable
@InjectView(R.id.edtEventLocationAddress)
private EditText edtEventLocationAddress;
```

now this view may or may not be present in the given layout i provided in the onCreateView method

this is why i put `@Nullable` on it

however, when I run the app, with the layout that does not have this view, I get

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't inject null value into class 
com.myapp.CreateEventPageFragment.edtEventLocationAddress when field is not @Nullable
```

What do I need to do to make roboguice allow me to reuse fragments, and only change their view ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A late answer but just in case anyone else stumbles on this.

You are probably using `android.support.annotation.Nullable` or a similar annotation that has `@Retention(RetentionPolicy.CLASS)` (or `RetentionPolicy.SOURCE`). However, you need to use a `@Nullable` annotation that is retained at runtime for RoboGuice to find it. E.g. this one:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.METHOD,
    ElementType.PARAMETER,
    ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Nullable {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Import `javax.annotation.Nullable` instead of `android.support.annotation.Nullable` as it has runtime retention policy (see Michael.F answer).

Comment: You cannot use `javax` as this is tagged as "android"

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility (which is how I ended up on this question) is that you have a typo in your XML file or in the Inject command, and it's trying to inject `null` because it didn't actually find the ID you specified.